# What is the best way to load spring config xmls?

Tags: spring, spring-mvc

I have to load 3 spring config xml files in myproj spring mvc app named myproj-controllers.xml, myproj-services.xml and myproj-dao.xml. I have two options to load them.

Firstly Use import resources in myproj-servlet.xml

```
<import resource="myproj-controllers.xml"/>
<import resource="myproj-services.xml"/>
<import resource="myproj-dao.xml"/>
```

or secondly in the web.xml using context param like this

```
<context-param>
   <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
   <param-values>/WEB-INF/myproj-controllers.xml</param-values>
   <param-values>/WEB-INF/myproj-services.xml</param-values>
   <param-values>/WEB-INF/myproj-dao.xml</param-values>
</context-param>
```

and adding ContextLoader listener

```
    <listener>
        <listener-class>org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener</listener-class>
    </listener>
```

Which approach is recommend? And why? In my opinion I find import approach easier as we only need to make changes to myproj-servlet.xml instead of web.xml.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Spring lets you declare multiple contexts in a parent-child relation so I always went for one root `applicationContext.xml` containing my application beans (services, DAOs etc) and one `action-servlet.xml` for servlet contexts (request mappings, view resolvers etc).

I once needed `action-servlet-2.xml` file but still had just one root `applicationContext.xml` for both servlet contexts.

So (for me) it was always **parent context + child context**.

The only need for splitting the files into more pieces was just to reduce the size of the XMLs (which is what `<import>` does best).

For me, the `contextConfigLocation` param refers to application context files being loaded together into a single application context instance. But your files (`myproj-controllers.xml`, `myproj-services.xml`, `myproj-dao.xml`) seem like **parts of one application context file**.

For this reason I would personally go for the `<import>` statements and have just one value (for the root application context) in the `contextConfigLocation` param.

Comment: Hi, I was not aware of the parent context + child context, if it is mentioned in spring documentation I might have overlooked it altogether. Could you pl refer me a link for further reading? Thanks.

Comment: @user354161: This is mentioned in the Spring reference, but unfortunately it is scattered information instead of being emphasized in one place. Nevertheless the [ApplicationContext](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/2.5.5/api/org/springframework/context/ApplicationContext.html) javadoc mentions it: _Inheritance from a parent context. Definitions in a descendant context will always take priority. This means, for example, that a single parent context can be used by an entire web application, while each servlet has its own child context that is independent of that of any other servlet._

Answer (score 0):

I prefer the context loader listener approach, but perhaps that's because I've never considered the import method.  I'll try it out.  Thanks.

I don't see any performance advantages.  The WAR file has to be redeployed in either case.  It's modifying one file as opposed to another.  I don't see any difference.  It has a bike shed feel to me, but I could be wrong.